# Passing Leaflet object geometries to a parametric SQL view in GeoServer

Tags: leaflet

I have a parametric SQL view for a WFS layer in GeoServer with the simplified form:

```sql
SELECT pts.id AS id, pts.geom as geom
FROM schema_name.points_table pts
WHERE ST_Contains(%g%, pts.geom);
```

I want to use this query as a filter for a Leaflet app, in which the user can edit a polygon to get only points in a defined area. Which steps are necessary to pass the geometry of my `L.polygon` object through the *`viewparams`* parameter into the `%g%` placeholder in my query?

Comment: You simply need to get the WKT or WKB of the polygon from Leaflet, then wrap it in the relevant st_geometryfromwkt function in your where clause. - Alternatively you could use a CQL filter on a normal layer with the same input